# How can I have dropdown "chunks of inputs"?

Tags: r, shiny

I know the title is not very clear so here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(dqshiny)

ui <- miniPage(
  fillRow(flex = c(1, 1),
          fillCol(
            dq_accordion(
              id = "something",
              titles = list("First",
                            "Second"),

              contents = tagList(
                tagList(selectInput("foo",
                                    "foo",
                                    choices = names(mtcars))),

                tagList(
                  textInput("foo_2", "foo 2"),
                  textInput("foo_3", "foo 3"),

                  checkboxInput("foo_4",
                                "foo_4",
                                value = TRUE)
                )
              )
            )
          )
          )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, when opening the first `dq_accordion` (I really don't know how to name this), there is a big white space that is due to the fact that the space below each `dq_accordion` is equal to the biggest space in one of the `dq_accordion`. Here, for example, there are more inputs (and hence a bigger space) in the second `dq_accordion`, which creates a white space in the first one. This is quite annoying because if I have a `dq_accordion` with a lot of inputs and one with one or two inputs, then the latter will display a big white space.

Do you know if there is a way to remove this white space? If not, do you know if another package provides this sort of dropdown panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative with `bsCollapse()` and `bsCollapsePanel()` from the `{shinyBS}` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- miniPage(
  fillRow(flex = c(1, 1),
          fillCol(
            bsCollapse(
              id = "something",
              bsCollapsePanel(
                title = "First",
                tagList(selectInput("foo",
                                    "foo",
                                    choices = names(mtcars))
                        )
              ),
              bsCollapsePanel(
                title = "Second",
                tagList(
                  textInput("foo_2", "foo 2"),
                  textInput("foo_3", "foo 3"),

                  checkboxInput("foo_4",
                                "foo_4",
                                value = TRUE)
                )
              )
            )
          )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```